# How can I read and show what's inside of a $scope-object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, undefined

This might be a little bit stupid question but I would like to know...

```
$scope.rma.retailerRetailerId = retailerService.get({id: retailerNumber});
console.log("address-1--->" + $scope.rma.retailerRetailerId.address);
```

----> In console: address-1--->undefined

But in view/html it is working normally, why is that? How can I see what is inside of the object in controller? Why it shows me that it is undefined even if there is data inside of it?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="rma.retailerRetailerId.address" placeholder="Address">
```

**Update - I added code of service**

```
angular.module('retailerService', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('retailerService', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource(

                    'http://localhost:8080/RmaServer/webresources/com.rako.rma.retailer/:id',
                    {},
                    {

                        update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: 'retailerNumber'} }
                    });
        }]);
```

Comment: do you have a plunkr? Should be working

Comment: Sorry, no. I thought that it is the right way, but no. retailerRetailerId object--->[object Object] (17:15:13:247) 
address-1--->undefined (17:15:13:249)

Comment: i think your console.log have no idea what is your object because the GET method is asynchronous and so, your adress is still undefined when you try to call your console.log..  try to handle your adress in callback of your GET.

Comment: @Charly - Could you tell me how to do it? I am using ngResource, factory and $resource to handle REST calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your console.log have no idea what is your object because the GET method is asynchronous, and so your adress is still undefined when you try to call your console.log.. try to handle your adress in callback of your GET.

```
retailerService.get({id: retailerNumber})
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log(data.adress)
    $scope.adress = data.adress //(example, idk how you manage your object)
  })
```

And you can make that differently with this:

```
$scope.adress = retailerService.get({id: retailerNumber})
```

And in your html you can use like that:

```
ng-model='adress.adress' //(ok here, it's really ugly :) )
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question. Basically I don't care could I see object in controller or not, because it is working fine in the view. I just wanted to know :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access $scope from console you need to use jQuery plugin `scope` (added by Angular).

```
console.log("address-1--->" + $('.form-control').scope().rma.retailerRetailerId.address));
```

I think that this will also work:

```
console.log("address-1--->" + angular.element('.form-control').scope().rma.retailerRetailerId.address));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried the first one and the result was the same, undefined.